# What Mac apps are capable of managing SQL Server databases?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, database

I'm looking for a Mac app that has capabilities similar to Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Manager.

The app should be capable of the following:

- Create and administer SQL Server databases, objects, logins, users,
  and permissions
- Define and execute SQL Server administrative tasks
- Design and test SQL statements, batches, and scripts

Is an app like that available today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Navicat offers a few products](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlserver/sqlserver_overview.html) that can connect and manager a MSSQL Server. Their apps are available on the Mac App Store as well.

I have used their MySQL edition, as well as their lowest-cost option, Essentials (I think they used to have a free version).

While I haven't used it for all of the items you have below, it was great for some simple table management tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You may like [SQLPro for MSSQL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sql-client-database-management/id828466809?mt=12). (You can also get a trial [at our website](http://macsqlclient.com))

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Syntax highlighting.
- Intellisense.
- Tabbed based interface.
- Support for executing multiple queries at once.
- Quick access to tables, columns and more.
- Stored procedure execution.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Comment: @Zanox Hi, does your app allow us to _create_ a local MS SQL database on our mac OS X? Or do you know of any software or ways to create a MS SQL database on a mac to be used locally only?

Comment: @RǢF, the app allows you to connect to a MSSQL server. It sounds like your looking to HOST a MSSQL server on OS X which I do not know of a way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

[Froq](http://www.colourful-apps.com/products/mac/froq) supports multiple databases including SQL Server. I have used this app for Oracle and really like it. Can't speak to specifics of SQL Server support.

The author is also very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net) which is cross-platform. It works great and supports so many data bases including SQL Server.

It's Open source and free.

Comment: Last I checked, Squirrel's supporting plugin for MSSQL did not work at all. Did they fix it?

Comment: @Priyeshj Yes I have heard now its working good

Comment: I tried just now, and the Microsoft MSSQL Server Driver doesn't seem to work for me out of the box (with the plugin installed). Moreover, it doesn't use the KeyChain on MAC and stores passwords as plain text. So it has been a turn off for me. Switched over to SQL Client, and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Priyeshj Thanks for pointing out what works for you, but it's not free right !

Comment: SQL Client costs $20 after trial ends. It is worth it when cutting the time I used to try all the other free options out.

Comment: @Priyeshj Thanks for pointing out SQL Client I'll try